# Finding a ratio to multiply RGB values by to get multiple tints of a color in Python

Tags: python, rgb, color-coding

I am trying to create a function to calculate tint based off a given rgb value and given number of tints. So the user will give an rgb value such as (100,200,150) as well as how many tints they want to be printed. The program will then print out that many colors with the first color printed, being the color given and then each color after that getting brighter till it reaches white, which is (255,255,255).

For example:
User input: red = 255, green = 0, blue=0, and numTints = 5

This will print: red,brighter red,brighter red,brighter red,white

The user can enter how ever many tints they want.

I understand that I need to multiply each rgb value by a constant greater than one until each value reaches 255. What I need help with is how to find that contant to multiply each value by.

Comment: What code do you have so far? You can try dividing the rgb values into equal intervals based on the number of tints you have. Also, if you're trying to go from red->white, you're going to be changing the green and blue values while holding the red value constant.

Comment: The color doesn't have to be red, it can be any color.  I did the same thing with shades, so the same only starting with the base color and going to black or (0,0,0) in RGB. This is the code I used for that.     ratio = (1/largest)**(1/tint)
    r = round(r * ratio, 0)
    g = round(g * ratio, 0)
    b = round(b * ratio, 0)

Comment: So basically I need help finding the equation to calculate the ratio to multiply the red, blue, and green value by to get to white. (255,255,255)

Comment: Basically whatever color shade you want, you're going to be changing the other two color values. You can just do equal intervals between whatever value you're starting at and 255, ie if the color value you start at is 100 and you want 5 tints, then your intervals would be 131, 162, 193, 224, 255.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create a function that takes two integers and returns numbers that lie evenly spaced between them. Then apply that function to each of your red, blue, and green channels of your colors.

```
"""returns a list of length `size` whose elements are evenly distributed between start and end"""
def interpolate(start, end, size):
    delta = float(end - start) / (size-1)
    return [start + i*delta for i in range(size)]

def interpolate_color(start, end, size):
    red   = interpolate(start[0], end[0], size)
    green = interpolate(start[1], end[1], size)
    blue  = interpolate(start[2], end[2], size)
    return zip(red, green, blue)

start = (100,200,150)
end = (255,255,255)
for c in interpolate_color(start, end, 5):
    print c
```

Result:

```
(100.0, 200.0, 150.0)
(138.75, 213.75, 176.25)
(177.5, 227.5, 202.5)
(216.25, 241.25, 228.75)
(255.0, 255.0, 255.0)
```